# Select all BEM modifiers in CSS/LESS

Tags: css, less, bem

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="my-grid">
    <div class="my-grid__row item">
        <div class="item__statusA"></div>
        <div class="item__statusB"></div>
        <div class="item__statusC"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select all `item__status*` but can't seem to do it in LESS. So far I've tried:

```
.item {
    &__ {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to select all the classes without creating seperate ones?

Comment: Without nesting, you can do: `div[class^="item__"]`.

Comment: `.item__status { &A, &B, &C {color: red} }` - Less can't do any `*` for you since it has no idea what your HTML is. So plain CSS `attr`-based selector (i.e. `[class^="item__status"]`) similar to what is suggested by @robjez would be more clean.

Comment: Maybe you should consider to use three time an element `.item__status` with three modifiers `A`, `B`, `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong to want it, and I doubt that this is possible.

The right way to create a modifier for the element, HTML structure:

```
<div class="my-grid">
    <div class="my-grid__row item">
        <div class="item__status item__status_A"></div>
        <div class="item__status item__status_B"></div>
        <div class="item__status item__status_C"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

LESS

```
.item {
    &__status {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Or a [mix](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes) of elements, HTML structure:

```
<div class="my-grid">
    <div class="my-grid__row item">
        <div class="item__statusA item__someElemforSemantic"></div>
        <div class="item__statusB item__someElemforSemantic"></div>
        <div class="item__statusC item__someElemforSemantic"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

LESS

```
.item {
    &__someElemforSemantic {
        color: red;
    }
}
```